# What is aerodynamic imbalance?

Tags: propeller, weight-and-balance

What is aerodynamic imbalance on a propeller? The most amount of hint I got was the shape of the airfoil. All I know is that it is the different thrust each prop blade produces due to different angles on each blade station. I am looking for a more in detail explanation and some examples.

Answer (score 2):

I think he wants to know that you have an understanding of [P Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-factor), which is the main "imbalance" or thrust asymmetry issue that has a direct impact on you as the pilot when you fly the plane.